# ImportError: cannot import name chardet

Tags: python, py2exe

Hi i have written a python **scraper** in which i am importing requests and Beautiful soup module . I am using python2.7 .
I am crating Windows executable (.exe) from my Python script using py2exe module.
For that i have created setup.py as following :

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import requests

packages = [
    'requests',
    'requests.packages',
    'requests.packages.chardet',
    'requests.packages.urllib3',
    'requests.packages.urllib3.packages',
    'requests.packages.urllib3.contrib',
    'requests.packages.urllib3.util',
    'requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname',
]

setup(
    console=['CompanyScraper-1.6.py']
    )
```

I have created .exe file by running command "python setup.py py2exe".
But while running the .exe file on window it throwing following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CompanyScraper-1.6.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "requests\__init__.pyc", line 58, in <module>
  File "requests\utils.pyc", line 26, in <module>
  File "requests\compat.pyc", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name chardet
```

i could not undaerstand why this chardet import error though i have included package into setup.py

Thanks you for looking into  my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the traceback -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CompanyScraper-1.6.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "requests\__init__.pyc", line 58, in <module>
  File "requests\utils.pyc", line 26, in <module>
  File "requests\compat.pyc", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name chardet
```

You have a `requests` directory with a `__init__.py` . This is masking the `requests` package from the library , so when you try to import `chardet` or any such thing from `requests` library , it tries to search for it in this local package, and not the library one.

The best solution for this would be to rename the directory and your local package from `requests` to something else, so that the name does not conflict with any library packages.

Comment: Thanks Anand for your guidance its working now,  Rather than renaming the local requests package i have copy the missing chardet folder into local requests library and its working fine . .... thanks :-)