# Exe file says - cannot import name chardet

Tags: python, exe, python-requests, py2exe, chardet

I'm trying to make an `exe` file using `py2exe`. The problem is that when I try to run created `exe` file, it returns that it cannot import name chardet.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "orsr_parser.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "requests\__init__.pyc", line 58, in <module>
  File "requests\utils.pyc", line 26, in <module>
  File "requests\compat.pyc", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name chardet
```

I use requests module in one of the py files in the program.

`Setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
packages = ['requests']
setup(console=['my_script.py'])
```

Do you know where could be the problem? Is there something with `setup.py` file?

EDIT: There is only one answer for this problem: [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31388067/3371056), but I probably don't get it. There is no directory called requests in my project.

Comment: It seems like a missing dependency , try and add chardet in the required packages in the setup.py